# how to import file that reside in two up directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I already knew that the operator './' 'is used to access files in the same directory.
and operators '../' to access files that are in one-up directory,
but how can I access the files in two to directories, like this:

```
src
| --dir1`
| | --dir2
| | --file1.js
file2.js
```

In this example I whan to import file2.js of file1.js, I have tried '... / file2' but it did not work.
how can I import file2 from file1 in this example?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: inside **file1**, do this `import file2 from  '../../file2'`;

Answer (score 3):

You can stack `../` like `'../../filename.extension'`.